# Unable to resize images in chrome using jhtmlarea plugin

Tags: jquery, html, editor, jhtmlarea

I am unable to resize images in chrome using jhtmlarea plugin.

I have tried this in:
http://pietschsoft.com/demo/jhtmlarea/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Safari are both based on Webkit, which has a rich text editing engine that doesn't have resize handlers yet. There's a jQuery plugin available though, to implement resizing on Webkit for a variety of WYSIWYG html editors:

[EditorBoost webkit resize plugin for iframe-based html editors](http://www.editorboost.net/Webkitresize/Index)

[EditorBoost webkit resize plugin for non-iframe-based html editors](http://editorboost.net/WYSIWYGResize/NonIframeDemos)